# How to overwrite the table rows by another Table if they are duplicate rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake which has some data like below

Table 1(snowflake table)

```
LOCATIONID  OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC    source_record_id                                            Value
LFOB        201001000001.00         cw_altdata:LFOB_historical_hourly.txt:2020-12-23_003400:1   3
LFOB        201001000002.00         cw_altdata:LFOB_historical_hourly.txt:2020-12-23_003400:2   3
```

and for the existing table I need to append the data and remove the duplicates based on first 2 columns

Table 2(Need to append to the existing table)

```
LOCATIONID  OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC    source_record_id                                            Value
LFOB        201001000001.00         cw_altdata:LFOB_historical_hourly.txt:2020-12-24_003400:3   4
LFOB        201001000002.00         cw_altdata:LFOB_historical_hourly.txt:2020-12-24_003400:4   4
```

after appending the Table 2 data. I want the duplicate data to be removed from table. My output table should be looking this.

```
LOCATIONID  OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC    source_record_id                                            Value
LFOB        201001000001.00         cw_altdata:LFOB_historical_hourly.txt:2020-12-24_003400:3   4
LFOB        201001000002.00         cw_altdata:LFOB_historical_hourly.txt:2020-12-24_003400:4   4
```

Here we can see duplicate rows has been removed. It should keep latest date. for eg: here **2020-12-24_003400** is latest date than previous table 1.

I only know some basics of sql statements. I did not find any articles regarding this, so did not get a chance to try any solutions. It would be a great help if someone has a solution.

Comment: Look into using an upsert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE is an the most expensive DML in Snowflake (and just about every other RDBMS). IF the number of rows in Table 2 is a significant percentages of Table 1 AND a significant percentages will result in UPDATE instead of INSERT, the following technique is an alternative:

DELETE FROM TABLE_1 T1  WHERE (T1.LOCATIONID, T1.OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC)
IN (SELECT T2.LOCATIONID, T2.OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC FROM TABLE_2 T2);

INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (SELECT * FROM TABLE_2);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to eliminate rows duplicate across all columns in the table (and assuming no duplicates in Table_1:

INSERT INTO TABLE_1
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_2
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1)

or, if the table has many columns:

INSERT INTO TABLE_1
(SELECT * FROM TABLE_2 T2
WHERE (T2.LOCATIONID, T2.OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC)
NOT IN
( SELECT
LOCATIONID, OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC
FROM TABLE_T2
MINUS
SELECT
LOCATIONID, OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC
FROM TABLE_T1)

Comment: Hi @jefferyJacobs the second query isnt working for me. It gives the below error

SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 313 unexpected '<EOF>'.
do you have any idea what this error indicates

Comment: Added closing Bracket at the end it worked. Thank you

Comment: The querry isnt giving any results. It is appending the duplicate data to Table_1;)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to do. You want to UPDATE existing rows based on the first 2 columns and I assume add new rows from Table 2. This isn't the same as you problems statement. You aren't "appending and deleting duplicates". As suggested, look at using MERGE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a merge statement to update table_1 with the values from table_2 when they are different for the business key (assuming in this case that the business key is LOCATIONID, OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC).  If the business key does not exist in table_1 the merge statement will insert the row.

Here is the merge:

```
merge into table_1
using(SELECT LOCATIONID,  
             OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC,    
             source_record_id,                                            
             Value
      FROM table_2
     ) table_2
     on table_1.LOCATIONID = table_2.LOCATIONID
     and table_1.OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC = table_2.OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC
WHEN MATCHED
and  table_1.source_record_id is distinct from table_2.source_record_id or
     table_1.value            is distinct from table_2.value
THEN UPDATE
SET  table_1.source_record_id = table_2.source_record_id,
     table_1.value            = table_2.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT
     (
      LOCATIONID,  
      OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC,    
      source_record_id,                                            
      Value
     )
VALUES
     (
      table_2.LOCATIONID,  
      table_2.OBSERVATION_TIME_UTC,    
      table_2.source_record_id,                                            
      table_2.Value
     )
;
```